# Assign multiple calls to a single variable or it does not matter for performance-wise

Tags: python, performance, python-requests

### Example #1:

```
import requests

r_get_obj = requests.get('http://localhost')
r__get__content = r_get_obj.text

if 'junior' in r__get__content:
   print('junior')
elif 'egg' in r__get__content:
   print('egg')
else:
   print('none')
```

### Example #2:

```
import requests

r_get_obj = requests.get('http://localhost')

if 'junior' in r_get_obj.text:
   print('junior')
elif 'egg' in r_get_obj.text:
   print('egg')
else:
   print('none')
```

As you can see, **example 1** assigns the request content to a variable then use it for checking,

But **example 2** doesn't assign it to a variable but keep calling `r_get_obj.text`.

My question is, does the ***2nd*** one have bad performance impact / bad non clean code, And which one is preferred?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do a quick dive & research in the `requests` library to come to a conclusion on what you should do. Notice the that the following:

```py
resp = requests.get("http://google.com")
type(resp)
```

Outputs:

```
<class 'requests.models.Response'>
```

Going into that class in their repo (`requests/models.py`), you end up at the class definition called [`Response`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/3e7d0a873f838e0001f7ac69b1987147128a7b5f/requests/models.py#L587):

```py
class Response(object):
    """The :class:`Response <Response>` object, which contains a
    server's response to an HTTP request.
    """

...
```

Scrolling down you will notice a property method called [`text`](https://github.com/psf/requests/blob/3e7d0a873f838e0001f7ac69b1987147128a7b5f/requests/models.py#L587), which is the method you are calling:

```py
...

    @property
    def text(self):
        """Content of the response, in unicode.
        If Response.encoding is None, encoding will be guessed using
        ``chardet``.
        The encoding of the response content is determined based solely on HTTP
        headers, following RFC 2616 to the letter. If you can take advantage of
        non-HTTP knowledge to make a better guess at the encoding, you should
        set ``r.encoding`` appropriately before accessing this property.
        """

...
```

This method does some encoding before returning the resulted (and expected) `text` variable every time; that is, it does so *without caching*. In this case it is likely better practice to simply just cache it yourself and not have to worry about (abuit, minor) performance issues:

```py
resp = requests.get("http://google.com")
html = resp.text
```

Comment: Thanks a lot boss, I appreciate your answer

Comment: No problem, glad it helped.